# Avoiding duplicate index in columns in table when using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below is my plunker in which I'm tring to display the output types based on different months.I want to save the maximum capacity for each month on click of save button by getting all the values in an array.But when I type in a text box the value gets repeated as the index is repeated column wise.

[ng-repeat in table](http://plnkr.co/edit/T0WJFs2b62GVbHzOxtzE?p=preview)

Below is the code:

JavaScript:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';

    $scope.outputType=["Coal","ROM","WASTE"];
    $scope.months=["JAN","FEB","MARCH","APRIL"];
    $scope.values = [];
    $scope.save=function(){
        alert($scope.values)
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
  <table style="border:1px solid red;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th ng-repeat="i in months"><b>{{i}}</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in outputType">
        <tr>
            <td>{{item}} </td>
            <td ng-repeat="i in months">
                <input type="text" ng-model="values[$index]"
                       placeholder="Max.Capacity">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please [edit] in the relevant code as text in your post.  External links are no substitute for code in the post itself.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I didn't get your comment

Comment: Your question contains no code.  Please include the code.  I noticed you have a link to a plunker, so copy some of the relevant code from the plunk into your question.  All posts on SO must be able to stand alone in case any external resources break.

Comment: Also, your link doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that http://plnkr.co/edit/4DUDIBoTOCI4J89FiQeM?p=preview

JS

```
$scope.values = {};
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="values[item][i]"  placeholder="Max.Capacity">
```

or

```
<input type="text" ng-model="values[i][item]"  placeholder="Max.Capacity">
```

Comment: So after saving the data do I need to have JSON in a similar format as you have shown so that I can bind them back?

Comment: Can you explain what was the cause of the problem and why this fixes it?

Comment: I wanted to bind the data back.So I wanted to know the JSON format to bind the values back into the text box at correct positions

Comment: updated plunker. I have no idea what are you doing and what is your JSON format. I just showed you how you can enter and print out your results, using two dimension map from JS and Angular perspective.

Comment: Also can you pls help me in modifying data in  $scope.values as  [
    {
        "name": "Coal",
        "month": "JAN",
        "value": 32
    },
    {
        "name": "ROM",
        "month": "FEB",
        "value": 37
    },
    {
        "name": "Waste",
        "month": "MARCH",
        "value": 34
    }
   
    
]

Answer (score 1):

Solution if you want to leave an **array**.

You need to change your **ngModel** in input

`<input type="text" ng-model="values[$index]" placeholder="Max.Capacity">`

to

`ng-model="values[$parent.$index][$index]"`.

Here is an example:

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/cuWTtABF7S86zI6dZyYw?p=preview)